# Color of the left class isnt changing when i hover over the test class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to change the colour of the div with class 'left' when i hover over the text with class 'test' but when I do it nothing happens is there a way to fix this?

I tried removing the 'side' class from the div with the 'left' class but that did nothing as expected

```css
.title {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 50px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.title:hover {
  color: red;
}

.left {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

.title:hover+.left {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sides">
  <div class="side left"></div>
  <div class="side right"></div>
  <div class="side top"></div>
  <div class="side bottom"></div>
</div>
<h1 class="title">Test</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` is the immediate sibling selector and `.left` isn't a sibling of `title`. You can try the newish [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) selector though:

```css
.title {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 50px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.title:hover {
  color: red;
}

.left {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

body:has(h1.title:hover) div.sides>div.left {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sides">
  <div class="side left"></div>
  <div class="side right"></div>
  <div class="side top"></div>
  <div class="side bottom"></div>
</div>
<h1 class="title">Test</h1>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote and/or accept the answer if it helped you. You'll earn rep for it too

Comment: it says i need more reputation to cast a vote ive just got back into programming recently so ive just logged into my old stack overflow account and it had no rep so it says i cant cast a vote until i have 15 rep. thanks again for the help